# When editing css code within a Typescript file in Vscode all the text is red, how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, visual-studio-code

Here is a picture of what's happening
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXUJ.png
And here's the code.

```typescript
export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    background-image: url(${BGImage});
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  * {
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Because it's inside TypeScript then it's seen as a string (template string as it's between backticks `\``) without any special context. If you want syntax highlighting, stick it in a .css file.

Comment: So it would fix itself if I just put the css code in it's own file?

Comment: Yep, but then you would have to set the background image a different way.

Comment: you could use the extension [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components)

Comment: why create an answer that is a comment to an answer that the answer works

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow, will try not to repeat this

Comment: @søvold there is a guide on what to do when your question [gets answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Your answer, which should be a comment, will probably get deleted. Also, I'm glad the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components) can help format and colorize your code in styled components or similar in different files, including `.tsx`, The example above, for me, looks like:

[image: Code formatted with the extension]

The red underlines are due to missing TypeScript types / functions for the underlined variables.